# segmentation fault when creating two different Binary trees in c++

Tags: c++, tree, segmentation-fault

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct tree
{
  int data;
  struct tree *leftchild;
  struct tree *rightchild;
};

typedef struct tree* Binary_tree;

//this function Creates a new node and assigns memory to it 
Binary_tree CreateNode(int value)
{
  Binary_tree temp;
  temp = new struct tree;
  temp->data = value;
  temp->leftchild = NULL;
  temp->rightchild = NULL;
  return temp;
}


//this function links nodes with each other
Binary_tree AddNode(Binary_tree head,int value)
{
  Binary_tree temp = head;
  if(head == NULL)
  {
    Binary_tree newNode = CreateNode(value);
    head = newNode;
  }
  else if(head->leftchild == NULL)
  {
    Binary_tree newNode = CreateNode(value);
    temp->leftchild = newNode;
  }
  else
  {
    Binary_tree newNode = CreateNode(value);
    temp->rightchild = newNode;
  }
  return head;
}


void PrintTree(Binary_tree head)
{
  if(head == NULL)
  exit;
  else
  {
    Binary_tree temp = head;
    cout<<temp->data<<endl<<temp->leftchild<<"\t\t"<<temp<<endl<<temp->rightchild<<endl;
    PrintTree(temp->leftchild);
    PrintTree(temp->rightchild);
  }

}


int main()
{
  Binary_tree head,second;
  for(int i=1;i<12;i++)
  {
    head = AddNode(head,i);
    second = AddNode(second,i+2);
  }
  PrintTree(head);
  PrintTree(second);

}
```

The Error i'm getting is Segmentation Fault. and it arises only when i create 2 trees i.e. head and second. it is working fine when i'm only processing head tree,i don't understand what is causing the error.

i think the segmentation fault is because of storing these trees adjacent in memory but trees are non linear so this should not be a problem can someone tell what can be the issue

Comment: You should not hide a pointer type behind a typedef.

Comment: Where do `head` and `second` point to before you add values?

Comment: BTW: C and C++ are different languages. Please decide which one to use and only use that language tag.

Comment: Did your compiler create some warning "variable head used without initialization" or similar? If your compiler tells you something, listen to it. And enable all warnings.

Comment: `Binary_tree head, second;` -> `Binary_tree head = NULL, second = NULL;`

Comment: Yes, that's the line I was talking about. If you see something like `void PrintTree(Binary_tree head)` you don't see at first glance what it is. That's simply bad style and reduces readability

Comment: @impirios I hope now you know why you've got the segfault with your original program

Comment: @Jabberwocky i think it was that the header/Parent node was not NULL.but it worked when workin with only one tree. it would be great if you can tell why it happened.

Comment: Your variables ae not initialized and the compiler probably told you so, Uninitialized variables contain seemingly random values and using them uninitialized results in undefined behaviour (google that term). I have no idea why it workd with only one tree as you didn't provide the code. But keep in mind that "undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: Using uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour. They have indetermined value and when you use them, anything can happen. Undefined behaviour also means that is CAN crash, but it DOES NOT HAVE to crash. This is valid for 1 tree as well as for 2 trees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your program rewritten in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

I used best practices, such as using RAII to hold state instead of manually fiddling with pointers and new/delete, arranging for objects to be initialized by-default, etc.

One functional difference is that my trees are non-balanced binary search trees.  Your trees stop growing after 3 nodes.

You'll note that the code is actually simpler using these techniques.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct tree;
using Tree = std::unique_ptr<tree>;

struct tree
{
  int data = 0;
  Tree left;
  Tree right;
};

//this function Creates a new node and assigns memory to it 
Tree CreateNode(int value)
{
  Tree retval = std::make_unique<tree>();
  retval->data = value;
  return retval;
}

//this function links nodes with each other
Tree AddNode(Tree head, int value)
{
  if(!head)
  {
    return CreateNode(value);
  }

  if (head->data <= value)
  {
    head->right = AddNode( std::move(head->right), value );
    return head;
  }

  head->left = AddNode( std::move(head->left), value );

  return head;
}


void PrintTree(Tree const& head, int indent = 0)
{
  if(!head)
    return;

  auto do_indent = [indent]{
      for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        std::cout << "\t";
  };
  do_indent();
  std::cout << head->data << std::endl;
  //do_indent();
  //std::cout << head->left.get() << "\t\t" << head.get() << std::endl;
  //do_indent();
  //std::cout << head->right.get() << std::endl;

  PrintTree(head->left, indent+1);
  PrintTree(head->right, indent+1);
}


int main()
{
  Tree head,second;
  for(int i=1;i<12;i++)
  {
    head = AddNode(std::move(head),i);
    second = AddNode(std::move(second),6+(i+2)%6);
  }
  PrintTree(head);
  PrintTree(second);
}
```

The immediate problem with your code was that it used uninitialized memory; reading uninitialized memory can crash or not crash based on luck.  It also leaked and didn't actually build the tree you asked for.

A fun way to print these trees would be:

```
void PrintTree(Tree const& head, int indent = 0)
{
  auto do_indent = [indent]{
      for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        std::cout << "\t";
  };

  if(!head)
  {
    do_indent();
    std::cout << "." << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  PrintTree(head->left, indent+1);

  do_indent();
  std::cout << head->data << std::endl;

  PrintTree(head->right, indent+1);
}
```

where we first print left, then head, then right.  This looks more like a tree, and a single `.` for null trees.

This generates the output:

```
    .
1
        .
    2
            .
        3
                .
            4
                    .
                5
                        .
                    6
                            .
                        7
                                .
                            8
                                    .
                                9
                                        .
                                    10
                                            .
                                        11
                                            .
        .
    6
                .
            6
                .
        7
                    .
                7
                    .
            8
                .
9
            .
        9
            .
    10
                .
            10
                .
        11
                .
            11
                .
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8295cc682df76050).

Comment: can you tell how do i add nodes in this tree in a balanced way

Comment: @impirios `using` is similar to `typedef`, but unlike `typedef` it isn't backwards.  Balancing a binary tree is something you probably best should read from a chapter of a textbook; there are many, many ways to do it.

Comment: how is **typedef** backward i don't understand please explain

Comment: do you mean giving the name of the replacing data type first then the replacer?